# How to correct wrong values with Numpy difference in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I've been working on my data by Python. My data is imported as a numpy array by using `numpy.diff`. But it turns out a wrong set of values.

```
import numpy as np

mydata = np.array([1285, 1328, 1277, 1293,  200, 1284, 1266, 1273, 1252, 1233, 1208, 1166, 1200, 1173,
 1179])

print(np.diff(mydata))
```

And it shows:

```
[   43 65485    16 64443  1084 65518     7 65515 65517 65511 65494    34
 65509     6]
```

which is absolutely wrong!

Who can help me to deal with this problem?

Comment: Why are there no commas in your array? What is the `dtype` of the array you used? Note that if it is unsigned, it will make a wraparound, which explains the `65'5..` part. Likely the type is an `uint16`.

Comment: Try `np.diff(a.astype(int))`

Answer (score 2):

The type of your array is likely an `uint16`. Indeed:

```
>>> my_data =np.array([25,14], dtype=np.uint16)
>>> np.diff(my_data)
array([65525], dtype=uint16)
```

This happens since *unsiged* integers can not represent negative numbers, and thus a wraparound is the result.

You can change the type of your array, for example to `int32`:

```
>>> np.diff(my_data.astype(np.int32))
array([-11], dtype=int32)
```